# firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() return null when phoneAuth is linked with google sign-in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an application in which am using firebase `PhoneAuthCredential` and **Google sign-in** **(linked)** to sign in a user so that user can sign in with either phone number or google sign-in.

First, phone number is verified via otp then in next step phone auth is linked with google account  (till here everything works fine, I'm able to link accounts).
Problem arises when I try to use `firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()`, it return me null

I don't know what's going wrong as I am able to **get display name** when user is **first signed with google sign-in then linked to phone number.**

Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(Objects.requireNonNull(account));
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+account.getDisplayName()+" "+account.getPhotoUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //here getting display name
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately

            Toast.makeText(PhoneToGoogle.this, "It seems like you have cancelled Google Authentication!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);


    Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).linkWithCredential(credential) //linking with phoneAuth
            .addOnCompleteListener(PhoneToGoogle.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        saveUserProfileDataInFirebaseDataBase(Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getUser());
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneToGoogle.this, "linked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        showSignInFailedMessage((Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException())).getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}
 private void saveUserProfileDataInFirebaseDataBase(final FirebaseUser user){
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child(NAME).setValue(user.getDisplayName());
    //here getting display name null
}
```

Comment: You need to provide us with some code to work with.

Comment: code provided, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're expecting the Google account user name to override the phone auth user name that was originally associated with the Firebase account.  It turns out that it doesn't work this way.  When an account is first created, it inherits the user information from the provider that was used to verify their identity.  In the case of phone auth coming first, no name is known, so the account gets null.  *This value persists [until you write code to change it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).*

After initial phone auth, if any other account is linked to the original Firebase auth user, it does not inherit the user info from the linked account.

If you go the other direction - Google auth followed by phone auth, the null name from the phone auth account doesn't overwrite the name obtained from Google.

Comment: I think **UserProfileChangeRequest** may accomplish the task. Thank you!